# Error: "Missing required field" using embedded entities in Solr's DIH Configuration File

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I am trying to import multiple tables from a MySQL database using Solr's Data Import Handler (DIH). The DIH does not import data from the second table, 'detail'.

My database configuration file is

```
<document>
    <entity name="item" pk="ListingId" query="SELECT * FROM item as item where listingid=360245270">
        <entity name="detail" pk="ListingId" query="SELECT Body FROM detail where listingid='${item.listingid}'">
            <field column="Body" name="Body" />
        </entity>
     </entity>
</document>
```

I monitored the MySQL query log, and the two important queries that are executed are:

```
SELECT * FROM item as item where listingid=360245270

SELECT Body FROM listeditemdetail where listeditemdetail.listingid=''
```

Clearly, the '${item.listingid}' part in the configuration file is not working as required. I have tried different spellings for the table and column names but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Just a Try) Try removing the primary key and using the upper case e.g. :-

```
<document name="items">
    <entity name="item" query="SELECT * FROM item as item where listingid=360245270">
        <field column="LISTINGID" name="listingid" />
        <entity name="detail" query="SELECT Body FROM detail where listingid='${item.LISTINGID}'">
            <field column="Body" name="Body" />
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! The only change I had to to was change 'item.listingid' to 'item.LISTINGID'. It seems flawed that the DIH wouldn't work when it was lowercaps.

Comment: Do you know why my attempt didn't work? It would be great to understand the workings of the DIH so I can solve problems like this in the future.

Comment: yup DIH doesn't seem to work with lowercaps probably depending upon the database i presume cause we had faced the same issue working with Oracle.

Comment: It is strange. All the other identifies could be mixed-case; it was only the ${item.LISTINGID} that needed to be upper-case.