# Apache Solr results from entities with foreign key not displayed

Tags: mysql, apache, solr, entity, dataimporthandler

I have a problem with displaying and indexing some entities from a mysql database.

```
    <entity name="first_entity" pk="id" query="SELECT * FROM first_entity" >
        <field column="id" name="id" />
        <!-- some working fields here -->
        <entity name="second_entity" pk="id" query="SELECT testproperty FROM second_entity WHERE second_entity.id='${first_entity.id}'">
            <field column="id" name="secondentityId" />
            <field column="testproperty" name="myproperty" />
        </entity>
    </entity>
```

This is a snippet from my data-config.xml file.

The first entity gets indexed properly, but the second one is not shown in the results from the first entities. Is this normal?

I thought I would get a result with all available information for the first entity if I request one.

I didn't find anything related to results for this. Only how I define a entity beneath a other one.

I hope my problem is clear and thanks for helping out!

Edit:

The indexing process is significant longer with the second entity added to the config file, but the fetched rows/docs are the same as without the second entity. So I think solr does something more.. (the select query on each item..)

Comment: can you just try ${first_entity.ID} ... just a guess. ..

Comment: the database column is lowercase. so this shouldn't be a problem i think. but thanks in anyway.

Comment: it doesnt matter in db however i have faced issues with case. So you can just try.

Comment: I did now but it doesn't changed :-( Is there something I need to do in the schema.xml file? Can't find anything further than the data config on http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example or other sources. Also there is no example on how a query result should look like with this structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371630/error-missing-required-field-using-embedded-entities-in-solrs-dih-configurat. Can you debug a single id and check what is the value passed. Check DataImport with Debug it should list the queries and results.

Comment: have you defined fields in schema.xml for "secondentityId" and "myproperty"?